# IBM Message Broker Toolkit Installation Issue

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

When I am installing `IBM Message Broker Toolkit`, I'm getting the following error

> Failed to create executable extension
>   com.ibm.cic.agent.internal.adapters.nativeAdapter.win32.
>   WinPlatformOperationsProvider: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException:
>   Plug-in "com.ibm.cic.agent.core.nativeInstallAdapter.win32" was unable
>   to instantiate class
>   "com.ibm.cic.agent.internal.adapters.nativeAdapter.win32.WinPlatformOperationsProvider"

Could you please help me regarding this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sandipan , this is a known issue. It is documented here (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21441742).

You may want to check the length of the installation path , preferably make it shorter (C:\IBM\IntegrationToolkit90 & SDPShared). You may also want to check if the installer downloaded is corrupt (With download director it usually downloads fine , with HTTP download you can have issues) .

HTH